# Remove attributes from a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

**How do I remove all attributes from a Javascript object?**

For example; if I have the following 'class' how can I perform a reset and remove all its attributes:

```
function MyObject()
{
   this.type="blah";
   this.name="kkjkj";
}

MyObject.prototype.clearAttribs = function()
{
   // I want to remove name, type etc from 'this'

   // Maybe I can do the following?
   for (var key in this)
      delete this[key];
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: Do you want to delete only data properties or methods/function properties also?

Comment: @jfriend00 I dont want to delete prototype functions but if an object has an attribute with a function in it then I want to delete it. For eg; myObj.specFunct = function() {}; then I want to delete that.

Comment: Then, your current code is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems fine as is. Since [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description) will *not* delete a property from the prototype, you do not even need to use `hasOwnProperty`.